Why VS Code Suggesting @radix-ui Suggestions
While working in React JSX File,
The VS Code is suggesting @radix-ui suggestion. Also, suggest lucide-react sometimes.
Is there any way to stop vs code suggesting this suggestions.
enter image description here
I have not installed them on current project nor installed globally. Still facing this issue.

Shadcn UI is built on top of Radix UI. Those components are extended by Shadcn from the Radix UI. If you looked at your package.json file, you would notice that Radix UI is installed as part of your dependencies. Hence, they are automatically installed into your project every time you install a Shadcn package.

Just checked package.json file, got it! Thank you so much
